# Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch IOS 11 Crashlytics report only

Tags: ios

I know this issue has been answered before on different scenarios. I
 have followed max answers but could not able to resolve my issue.

**Step 1: main.m class**

```
    int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MYAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

**Step 2: On appdelegate**

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:authenticationStoryBoard
            bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        LaunchView *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:launchViewControllerID];

        self.window.rootViewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:rootViewControllerID];

        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[window rootViewController];

        navigationController.viewControllers = @[viewController];

return YES;
}
```

if possible can anybody help on this...

Comment: are you sure the ***viewController*** is NOT nil ?

Comment: Yes, @MehulParmar  I have verified...

Comment: about step-2... __which__ method's body does contain step-2 exactly?

Comment: @holex On appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions...I have just edited the question please check

Comment: @Bapu, what is about your `self.window`? do you init that anywhere?

Comment: @holex No.Is it mandatory to do "init"?

Comment: @Bapu, well... if you init everything manually, you should init the window as well; it will not be inited magically, however it is not quite clear why you do need initing everything manually here, why don't you just set up the storyboard file with an _initial view-controller_ and set up that storyboard as _main-interface_ for your project, so actually you'll get inited everything automatically after all...?